# Django QuerySet "row based" aggregation

Tags: django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model Foo which has m2m relationship with model Bar and model Baz, so it looks kinda like this:

```
Bar(0..*)----(1..*)Foo(1..*)----(0..*)Baz
```

What I'm trying to do is get the top n Foos by the number of associated Bars and Bazs combined.

Here's what I got so far:

```
Foo.objects.all() \
    .annotate(count_bar=(Count('bar')) \
    .annotate(count_baz=(Count('baz').extra(
        'select'={'total' : 'count_bar + count_baz'},
        'order_by'=('-total',)
    )
```

QuerySet looks good up untill `extra` call. Then I get `Unable to get repr for QuerySet`.
This would be a breeze if `F()` could be used in `annotate` call. Is there any ORM friendly way I could go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with retrieving all of the Foos with counts and sorting them with `sorted` using lambda as key.

Comment: The 'proper' solution would probably be to make Bar and Baz sub-classes of the same super-class, and have Foo m2m with that.